# How to emulate x86 Linux assembly on Windows

Tags: assembly, emulation

About a month ago, I set out to learn Assembly. However, after learning about syntax and the actual code of Assembly, I realized that I had learned Linux x86, while I have a Windows computer. I would like to know if there is a way to emulate x86 Linux assembly on Windows computers so that I do not have to re-learn everything. Is this possible?

Comment: Hem, the assembly language depends on the processor (x86), not on the operating system [if you missed that you should review your course :( ]. Maybe are you speaking of the assembler syntax ?

Comment: If all else fails, I'd use virtualization to fire up a VM with Linux... But still, that helps only with the tooling, the code (as Yves pointed out) is tied to the architecture, not the OS...

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, I mean the assembler syntax. I just want to run x86 on a non-x86-compatible pc.

Comment: `non-x86-compatible pc` wait, what?  I thought non-x86 Windows was mostly not a thing anymore, outside of Windows smartphones.  And the normal definition of "PC" means x86.  (If you have an ARM / MIPS / PowerPC / SPARC / IDK what desktop, you shouldn't call it a PC.)

Comment: Anyway, if you learned GNU AT&T syntax, that's fine.  You can assemble that on Windows with mingw gcc.  You only need to learn a different system-call API and ABI.  Assuming you're running Windows on a normal PC, it's still x86 and you can even still use the same syntax.

Comment: @BrianCompau don't worry, it is all good effort. The difference between different assembler syntax is relatively easy compared with understanding the details of how the processor works, which is the same. You'll be well placed to study other processors, and you'll catch on really quickly I am sure. But thinking you won't have to re-learn anything is a false idea: that is what this world is all about: continual uplifting. Once you have stepped onto that conveyor belt... your feet and fingers will not stop walking for a long time!

Comment: This will probably get a few groans, but if you have 64-bit Windows 10 and the anniversary update installed you could use Microsoft's WSL ([Windows Services for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)) to do development and run your Linux programs. This doesn't make them Windows Applications but it is useful if you do want to do Linux based development on Windows.

Comment: @MichaelPetch sadly my free upgrade from Win 8 to Win 10 is on a HDD sitting on a shelf (so that I can free revert if I choose). Meanwhile I am the happy customer who bought a refurb Win 7. Apart from the trashed UI quality (no option to use legacy), the last straw was when an update removed some apps I had installed.

Comment: OP: you have to re-learn the OS API (from Linux toward windows API). Which you probably don't need anyway, apart of tutorials displaying strings, as for low level stuff and API calls you can use C++, keep ASM only for writing some real code doing the actual things, where you need last bit of performance. If you learned AT&T syntax, then well.. you can still compile that even in windows.. or relearn the Intel syntax instead, and use that one even in linux. For hand written code I find AT&T too verbose and a bit longer. ... Or switch to Linux anyway (warning, I'm biased .... 10y linux user).

Answer (score 0):

well I don't know about assembly language, but it is possible to get a 32 bit environment on a 64 bit system. you can use a VM like virtualbox or VMWare and put in a 32 bit linux distro on it. that's probably the closet you'll get since assembly is one of (if not the) the lowest level programing language out there, that being the case there isn't an easy way to trick the system as nothing is abstracted.

I found this article stating it is possible to run a 32bit vm on a 64 bit system 
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=24663

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to not need a VM, but if it's all I can do, then it's fine!

Comment: But even then considering how low level assembly is, even running in a vm you might need to make some adjustments. as unlike with practically every other programing language where a lot of the methods and functions that are used by the code are abstracted in some way and it's that abstraction that the emulators take advantage of to make the code work on a system other then what it was designed for.